# CSS formatting problems - new to web design

Tags: html, css, formatting, positioning

I've followed various online tutorials (codeacademy, some reading, dash), and thought I was finally getting to grips with things.

I've made a couple of web pages of different styles, no backend functionality yet I'm talking about just the front end stuff.

I keep running into strange problems with regards to positioning things on the page and I'm really not sure where it is I'm going wrong. I know you cant answer in general where I'm going wrong as obviously each case will differ.

Basically I cant seem to manipulate the menu section in the way I want...I wanted the menu items to all be next to each other, and have a slightly different colour to the background of the ul. For some reason the background colour kept moving when I tried to have the li's as a different colour. Now that I have the whole thing as one colour, I cant change the margin of the li's to move them closer to each other.

Getting rather stressed with all this at the moment as it seems like easy things are very difficult so I must be making a major error somewhere. Are there any other tutorials anyone can suggest?

But in this specific case, what am I doing wrong? Is it the way I have arranged the HTML? The CSS? If I'm doing something majorly wrong then please point it out as I don't want to keep practicing the wrong thing.

```css
.banner .container{
background: #1D2926;
width: cover;
height: 50px;
margin: -10px -30px 0 -20px;
}

.banner .strip {
background: #E3C109;
height: 5px;
width: cover;
margin: 0px -30px 0px -20px;
}

body {
text-align: center;
}

.logo {
font: ;
color: #000;
background: url("");
margin-top: 150px;
margin-bottom: 80px;
height: 20px;
}

h1 {
font-size: 60px;
font-family: 'Niconne', cursive;
}

ul {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
}

li {
margin-left: 0 -2px 0 -2px;
display: inline;
font-size: 25px;
padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
font-family: 'Londrina Solid', cursive;
border: 1px solid #d3c5ba;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
 <div class="container">
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="strip">
  &nbsp;
 </div>
</div>

<div class="logo">
 <h1>Name of business</h1>
</div>

<div class="menu">
 <div class="container">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Drink</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Pennine Trail</a> </li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve (or where the problem is for that matter) - let the CSS box model guide you? (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Comment: `width: cover` is not valid CSS as far as I know. Try `width: 100%`

Comment: What's with all the negative margin amounts? It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish with that. Also, what is the point of the `div` with class `container` inside the `menu`? Let us know exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The negative margins were because the background styling I had at the top of the page, the banners and such, were not spanning the whole width or height of the page, meaning there was white space all the way around the rectangular boxes of colour. Is there another way to achieve this? I tried messing around with width 100% and width cover but it didn't change anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup looks fine, one of the best ways of learning HTML/CSS is trial and error.

The first issue I see on why your margin's on the li are not responding to your changes is because, you have your styles defined incorrectly on the margin-left style:

```
margin-left: 0 -2px 0 -2px;
```

It should be either:

```
margin-left: -2px;
margin-right: -2px;
```

or

```
margin: 0 -2px 0 -2px;
```

Comment: Ah yeah that will have been an oversight after an hour of stress changing things lol

Answer (score 0):

I have made some css changes to achieve whatever you had mentioned in your question. Check once if you wanted to have this.

```
.banner .container{
background: #1D2926;
width: cover;
height: 50px;
margin: -10px -30px 0 -20px;
}

.banner .strip {
background: #E3C109;
height: 5px;
width: cover;
margin: 0px -30px 0px -20px;
}

body {
text-align: center;
}

.logo {
font: 2em;
color: #000;
background: url("");
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h1 {
font-size: 60px;
font-family: 'Niconne', cursive;
}

ul {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
}

li {
margin-left: 0 -2px 0 -2px;
display: inline;
font-size: 100%;
padding: 0 3% 0 3%;
font-family: 'Londrina Solid', cursive;
border: 1px solid #d3c5ba;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look properly at this once I'm in front of my computer!

Answer (score 0):

**[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwBrLJ)**

Add `overflow: hidden` and `width: 100%` to the `ul`

```
ul {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Add `float: left` and `width: 16.5%`  to the `li's`

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family:'Londrina Solid', cursive;
    border: 1px solid #d3c5ba;
    width: 16.5%;
    float: left;
}
```

How I got the width of 16.5% is *100/6*. ***6*** is the number of links that you have on page and 100 is the width of the parent. So, if you add more or get rid of some links just do 100 divided by the number of links.

Comment: I know I could google this but specifically asking you, why do you choose float left for the li's? And why inline-block?

Comment: @DannyMallon  The reason why I used float: left and display: inline block is because float : left gets rid of the white space in between the li's and display: inline-block gets rid of the bullet points. I could take display: inline-block out and put on the ul {list-style: none}; And all would work just fine.  Here is a good read about it. https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @DannyMallon I also updated the codepen to resemble my comment.